# Curious JavaScript performance dependent on variable scope

Tags: javascript, performance, scope

When testing the performance of one JavaScript project, I noticed a very peculiar behavior - JavaScript member access performance seems to be heavily influenced by the scope they are in. I wrote a few performance tests, and the results were different by **multiple orders of magnitude**.

I tested on Windows 10 64-bit, using these browsers:

- Google Chrome, version 49.0.2623.75 m - uses the [V8 JavaScript engine](https://developers.google.com/v8)
- Mozilla Firefox, version 44.0.2 - uses the [SpiderMonkey JavaScript engine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey)
- Microsoft Edge, version 25.10586 - uses the [Chakra JavaScript engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra_(JavaScript_engine))

Here are the most relevant tests I ran and their respective results:

```
// Code running on global scope, accessing a variable on global scope
// Google Chrome:   63000 ms.
// Mozilla Firefox: 57000 ms.
// Microsoft Edge:  21000 ms.
var begin = performance.now();
var i;
for(i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) { }
var end = performance.now();
console.log(end - begin + " ms.");


// Code running on local scope, accessing a variable on global scope
// Google Chrome:   61500 ms.
// Mozilla Firefox: 47500 ms.
// Microsoft Edge:  22000 ms.
var begin = performance.now();
var i;
(function() {
    for(i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) { }
})();
var end = performance.now();
console.log(end - begin + " ms.");

// Code running on local scope, accessing a variable on local scope
// Google Chrome:   50 ms.
// Mozilla Firefox: 28 ms.
// Microsoft Edge:  245 ms.
var begin = performance.now();
(function() {
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) { }
})();
var end = performance.now();
console.log(end - begin + " ms.");
```

The difference between code running in local and global scopes was within the margin of error, *although Firefox did seem to get a pretty consistent 20% performance boost running in local scope*.

The biggest surprise was accessing a variable on a local scope, it was **1200 to 1600 times faster** on Chrome and Firefox, and 90 times faster on Edge.

Why would this be the case, on three different browsers / JavaScript engines?

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` is a really poor performance measurement tool. Use the Performance API to get much more accurate readings.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using the built-in Date function for this test.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I updated my code and test results to use the performance API, it had no noticeable effect. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: How can you be sure that the interpreter did not completely optimize the loop away? That seems quite likely give three orders of magnitude difference.

Comment: @torazaburo Because increasing the loop length `n` times proportionally increased the execution time `n` times. If it would have been optimized out, the execution time would be constant, and close to 0. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the actual machine code generated by the V8 JavaScript engine (same as used in Chrome) by running your code under [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and passing the `--print_opt_code` switch on the `node` command line. For example if you put your code in a file called `test.js` you can run:

```
node --print_opt_code test.js
```

In your last example, V8 is able to put the `i` variable in the `RAX` register instead of keeping it in memory. Here's the inner loop from the code printed out by the above command, with some extra notes. (There is additional code before and after; this is just the inner loop itself.)

```
 84  33c0           xorl rax,rax                 ; i = 0
 86  3d00e1f505     cmp rax, 0x5f5e100           ; compare i with 100000000
 91  0f8d12000000   jge 115                      ; exit loop if i >= 100000000
 97  493ba548080000 REX.W cmpq rsp, [r13+0x848]  ; check for bailout?
104  0f8246000000   jc 180                       ; bailout if necessary
110  83c001         addl rax, 0x1                ; i++
113  ebe3           jmp 86                       ; back to top of loop
115  ...
```

Note that `0x5f5e100` is `100000000` represented in hexadecimal.

As you can see, this is a fairly tight loop with only a few instructions. Most of the code is a direct translation of the JavaScript code; the only thing I'm a bit unsure about are the two instructions at addresses 97 and 104 that bail out of the loop if a certain condition is met.

If you run similar tests with your other versions of JavaScript code you will see much lengthier instruction sequences. Just be aware that Node wraps all of your code inside a wrapper function that it provides. So if you want to do something like your first example you may need to write the loop like this to get a similar effect:

```
for(global.i = 0; global.i < 100000000; global.i++) { }
```

Perhaps there is a way to tell Node to not use its outer wrapper function; I'm not familiar enough with Node to advise on that.

Comment: Perhaps node.js puts the wrapper function there *because* of the issue in this question? Because indeed - running all my examples are equally fast in node.js

Answer (score 4):

The variable in the global namespace will have much poorer performance, but not precisely for the reasons that @Freddie mentions. A variable in the global namespace could potentially be changed by something external, forcing the interpreter to reload the value each time through the loop. Using a local variable, the JIT engine can optimize the loop down to a few machine cycles per iteration, which is what seems to be happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this under Technique 1 - http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jkm3/index.html

> Global variables have slow performance because they live in a highly-populated namespace. Not only are they stored along with many other user-defined quantities and JavaScript variables, the browser must also distinguish between global variables and properties of objects that are in the current context. Many objects in the current context can be referred to by a variable name rather than as an object property, such as alert() being synonymous with window.alert(). The down side is this convenience slows down code that uses global variables.

Comment: Thanks, this *partially* answered my question. I would have accepted your answer if this was e.g. 2008 (which is when your given article was written), since then JS was a fully-interpreted language. However now all modern JS engines, at least the ones I tested on, utilize JIT compilation down to a low-level language. At which point namespace convolution seems like a non-issue. C++ for example doesn't have this, although I'm not sure if this is a fair comparison. I would've tested on C# too, which is also a JIT-compiled language, however sadly *(luckily?)* it doesn't have real global variables.

Comment: This seems unlikely to account for a difference of three orders of magnitude.

Comment: I reran the above tests on Chrome. Results today were:

[1] 1103 ms
[2] 1121 ms
[3] 350 ms.

The difference now is just 3 times faster for the local/local option.