# Is there a faster alternative to cosine/sine function?

Tags: javascript, performance, trigonometry

I really am struggling with how slow an inefficient the javascript sine and cosine functions are.  I'm making a first person shooter out of p5.js webgl and it's really causing a ton of lag.

Can someone tell me how to find the sine/cosine of an angle with *only one* angle?
or at least show me a more efficient way to do this?

So literally I'm trying to recreate the `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` functions to just simply run faster.

Comment: It would help if you can show how you are using it? And how have you tested that these functions are causing lag?

Comment: I am using the sine and cosine functions to make entities like Bullets and Particles move.  I just need to figure out how to solve the sine and cosine of an angle more efficiently with only a single angle given.

Comment: No.  Converting a degree to radians is not what I'm asking for.  I'm trying to get a faster way to calculate the sine and cosine of an angle.

Comment: What unit is the angle defined in then?

Comment: Does it still lag if you use a very simple function like a straight line in place of sin/cos ?

Comment: @DarkBee the input unit is Radians.

Comment: @Meowf it lags since I'm constantly having to call the sine and cosine functions.

Comment: Well, you'll need to provide some code in order to get help here - [ask]

Comment: Im going to go out on a limb and promise you that the sine and cosine functions are massively unlikely to be your bottleneck! re `So literally I'm trying to recreate the Math.cos and Math.sin functions to just simply run faster.`.

Comment: But there's nothing stopping you use a lookup table from degrees as per my answer. It's a bit harder to do for rads as you'd need to interpolate between values which will end up being slower

Comment: I guess I will repeat what I asked once more, does it lag if you replace all your calls to `sin` and `cos` with something like `angle % 1` (yes I mean it - just to keep the values in the same range as sin/cos). Disregard that it no longer does what you want it to, does it still lag? If it does you are not going to get improved performance as @Jamiec suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your degrees are only full integer degrees in the range 0-359, you could cache the result of the sin/cos in an array, where the degrees is the index of the array:

```js
const pi180 = (Math.PI/180);
const angles =[...new Array(360).fill(0)].map((_,i) => ({
  cos: Math.cos(i * pi180),
  sin: Math.sin(i * pi180)
}));
console.log(angles);
```

If you wanted for example the cos of 32 degrees it would be `angles[32].cos`

This is harder to do using radians, as you're dealing with floating point values and you'd need a way to either truncate or interpolate between values.

---

A short commentary on you believing `cos`/`sine` are your bottleneck: This is unlikely. Much more likely is that you're continually calling mathematical functions when it is unecessary. Check your code to make sure you only calculate things when they change, not on every keyframe of an animation and that you only invalidate parts of your code which has actually changed.

Comment: Seems there is already a [benchmark](https://jsben.ch/RGeU7) posted on SO as well - [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896703/why-is-precomputing-sinx-slower-than-using-math-sin-in-javascript)

Comment: I agree, that the bottleneck might be somewhere else. For my case, I struggled with constant object creations.. implementing instance pool solved it for me.

Comment: Anyway.. it seems, that the precision of such "database" can be optimized by multiplying by 10, extending the array the same way.